# Swapping diagonally split button the other way

Tags: html, css

I have a codepen (http://codepen.io/Nosdo3/pen/nktms/) that features a diagonal button. I have tried flipping it so that the split goes the opposite direction (starts top left goes to bottom right), but I just keep ending with a jumbled mess.

I am trying to make this button combo 300px wide and 65px tall.

```
#btn_cont{
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 10%;
    /* NOT IMPORTANT */

    width: 300px;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    height: 65px;
}
.btn-split{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    width: 158px;
    height: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.btn-split:nth-child(1){
    border-bottom: 60px solid #c74523;
    border-left: 20px solid transparent;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
.btn-split:nth-child(1):hover{
    border-bottom: 60px solid #fff;
    color: #c74523;
}
.btn-split:nth-child(2){
    border-right: 20px solid transparent;
    border-top: 60px solid #c74523;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}
.btn-split:nth-child(2):hover{
    border-top: 60px solid #fff;
    color: #c74523;
}

.btn-split:nth-child(2):before{
    border-right: 2px solid #fff;
    content: "";
    height: 71px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 138px;
    top: -35px;
    transform: rotate(34deg) translateZ(0px);
}
.btn-split span{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    top: 7px;
    width: 100%;
    height:auto;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.btn-split:hover span{
    color: #c74523;
}
.btn-split:nth-child(2) span{
    top: -23px;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Little different (simpler, imho) approach:

```css
body{
  background-color: #222;
}
H1{
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

#btn_cont{
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 10%;
  /* NOT IMPORTANT */
  overflow:hidden;
  width: 300px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  height: 65px;
  background:white;
}
.btn{
  display: block;
 
  position:absolute;
  width: 150px;
  height:100%;
  cursor: pointer;  
}

.right {
  background:#c74523;
  transform: skewX(-45deg);
  right:-30px;
  width:60%;
}

.left {
  background:#c74523;
  transform: skewX(-45deg);
  left:-30px;
  width:60%;
}
.right:hover, .left:hover {
  background:white;
}
.right:hover span, .left:hover span{
   color:#c74523;
}

span {
  float:left;

  width:50%;
  height:65px;
  line-height:65px;
  color:white;
padding-left:60px;
  position:relative;
  display:block;
    transform: skewX(45deg);
    
}
```

```html
<h1>CSS SPLIT BUTTON</h1>

<div id="btn_cont">


  <div class="btn left">
   <span>BTN 1</span> 
  </div>

   <div class="btn right">
   <span>BTN 2</span>
  </div>
```

You can tweak settings a little, but it should be close.

Answer (score 0):

> if you want to change the split to opposite direction add "-" before
>   34deg

/

```
transform: rotate(34deg) translateZ(0px);
```

\

```
transform: rotate(-34deg) translateZ(0px);
```

Comment: Much more to it than that. Please see the demo of the code or put it in a fiddle. This makes a mess.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use pseudo selectors, then you just have to swap out the border rules for each.

**Working Example:**

```css
body {
  background-color: #607D8B;
  padding: 25px 0 0;
}
/* OG */

.btn_cont_left {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
  border: 2px solid #FAFAFA;
  height: 30px;
}
.btn_cont_left .btn {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  width: 141px;
  height: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.btn_cont_left .btn:nth-child(1):before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 0px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 30px solid #01579B;
  border-left: 0px solid #01579B;
}
.btn_cont_left .btn:hover:nth-child(1):before {
  border-bottom: 30px solid #FAFAFA;
  color: #01579B;
}
.btn_cont_left .btn:nth-child(2) {
  right: 0;
}
.btn_cont_left .btn:nth-child(2):before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 30px solid #01579B;
  border-right: 0px solid #01579B;
  border-bottom: 0px solid transparent;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
}
.btn_cont_left .btn:hover:nth-child(2):before {
  border-top: 30px solid #FAFAFA;
  color: #01579B;
}
.btn_cont_left .btn:nth-child(2):after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 39px;
  top: -4px;
  right: 150px;
  border-right: 2px solid #FAFAFA;
  transform: rotate(-34deg) translateZ(0px);
}
.btn_cont_left .btn span {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  top: 7px;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FAFAFA;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.btn_cont_left .btn:hover span {
  color: #01579B;
}
/* NEW*/

.btn_cont_right {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
  border: 2px solid #FAFAFA;
  height: 30px;
}
.btn_cont_right .btn {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  width: 141px;
  height: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.btn_cont_right .btn:nth-child(1):before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 30px solid #b71c1c;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 0px solid transparent;
  border-left: 0px solid #b71c1c;
}
.btn_cont_right .btn:hover:nth-child(1):before {
  border-top: 30px solid #FAFAFA;
  color: #b71c1c;
}
.btn_cont_right .btn:nth-child(2) {
  right: 0;
}
.btn_cont_right .btn:nth-child(2):before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 0px solid transparent;
  border-right: 0px solid #b71c1c;
  border-bottom: 30px solid #b71c1c;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
}
.btn_cont_right .btn:hover:nth-child(2):before {
  border-bottom: 30px solid #FAFAFA;
  color: #b71c1c;
}
.btn_cont_right .btn:nth-child(2):after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 39px;
  top: -4px;
  right: 150px;
  border-right: 2px solid #FAFAFA;
  transform: rotate(34deg) translateZ(0px);
}
.btn_cont_right .btn span {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  top: 7px;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FAFAFA;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.btn_cont_right .btn:hover span {
  color: #b71c1c;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="btn_cont_left">
  <div class="btn">
    <span>BTN 1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="btn">
    <span>BTN 2</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="btn_cont_right">
  <div class="btn">
    <span>BTN 1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="btn">
    <span>BTN 2</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="btn_cont_left">
  <div class="btn">
    <span>BTN 1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="btn">
    <span>BTN 2</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="btn_cont_right">
  <div class="btn">
    <span>BTN 1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="btn">
    <span>BTN 2</span>
  </div>
</div>
```